# Visual Studio 2010: Constructor on type '###' not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, user-controls

I'm trying to put inhertance in my usercontrols but the designer is constantly giving me the error:

```
 Constructor on type "###" not found
 ### here is name of my parent usercontrol:
```

No other errors are being shown.
I've tried any of the following solutions offered on MSDN:

- Restart VS
- Build - Restart VS
- Clean - Build - Restart VS
- Remove - readd Usercontrol
- ...

For whom it may concern, the constructors:

Child (Type= Windows.forms.Usercontrol):

```
Public Class UC_Url
    Inherits Master

    Public Sub New(ByVal meter As UMeter)
         MyBase.New(meter)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
   End Sub

End Class
```

Parent (Type= Windows.forms.Usercontrol):

```
Public Class Master
     Implements ICloneable

     Public Sub New(ByVal meter As AMeter)

          ' This call is required by the designer.
          InitializeComponent()
          lblName.Text = meter.Caption
      End Sub

End Class
```

**Note:** UMeter (Child) inherits AMeter

Other posts on SO regarding this issue haven't helpen me sofar.

**Question:** Anyone has any experience handling this?

Thnx

Comment: It seems like you would need a parameterless constructor since the Designer would not know what to pass in for the value of meter.

Comment: Originally i didn't work when adding a parameterless constructor. But with a Clean + rebuild the problem got solved. Could you post it as answer so i can approve it?

Answer (score 1):

The argument should be the variable `meter` not the type `UMeter`:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal meter As UMeter)
     MyBase.New(meter)
...
```

Comment: That was a typo from mypart. I prefer to hide my actual classnames (privacy issues). The remark made by Chris Dunaway solved it for me. A   parameterless constructor does allow me to use the designer

Comment: This is strange. In C# the designer works even when the form has no default constructor.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same. I use inhertiance all the time in c#. but apparently vb.net has issues with it.

Comment: To be precise, in C# you can design a form or UserControl having no parameterless constructor; however you cannot place such a control on a form at design time! (The designer would not know which values to pass for the parameters).